# Programming R Related - insert into SQLQuery from object df

Tags: sql, r, insert-into

I am using R studio and I am trying to insert a dataframe object into a sql table but I am getting an error when I try the insertdata line.

error message is

> [1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'c'."
>   [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'insert into [tbl]c(118, 118, 122, 158, 2)'"

```
require(RODBC) 
require(sqldf)
df <- tst
df2 <- sqlQuery(channel,"SELECT * FROM [tbl]")
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT Id,Date,Desc FROM df WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM df2 WHERE df.Id = df2.Id) GROUP By Id,Desc,Date")
newdata <- sqldf("SELECT Id, Date, Desc from df3")
insertdata <- sqlQuery(channel,paste( "insert into table", newdata, sep = ""))
```

The table and dataframe both have 3 columns with the same class names which I checked with
`sapply(df2,class)
sapply(newdata,class)`

the classes show as factors so I don't know if this is my problem or if what I am trying to do is the best way of doing this.
Sample of newdata

```
Id       Date         Desc  
AA123A12 01/01/2012   Basic  
AD153A17 13/02/2017   Detailed  
AD163A17 19/03/2017   Basic
```

Sample of tbl data

```
Id       Date         Desc  
AR173A16 23/05/2016   Basic  
BN133H14 16/07/2014   Basic  
CC163B17 11/02/2017   Basic
```

Comment: You have a typo in line 5 `df3 < -sqldf("SELECT Id`; your assignment operator has a space in between `<` and `-`. Is that in your actual code, or was that just a typo on on your post?

Comment: Thanks this was just a typo in my post, thanks